# Javascript loading and mapping data from http request

Tags: javascript, typescript, subscription

In my application I have a server with a rest interface which handles all database entries. When the user logs into the aplication all user data should be loaded and mapped from database models to usable models. The difference is that the database models are only holding the ids of its child objects, while the normal model has its child object directly inherited. So to load all objects via http request from database and map them I build this:

```
class SomeClass {
  private loadProjectData(projectId: string): void {
    let s: Sheet;
    let d: Dashboard;
    this.databaseService.getDocument("Projects", projectId).subscribe(
      (project: ProjectDB) => {
        this.project = new Project(project.id, project.name, project.theme, []);
        for (const dash of project.dashboards) {
          this.databaseService
            .getDocument("Dashboards", dash)
            .subscribe((dashboard: DashboardDB) => {
              d = new Dashboard(dashboard.id, dashboard.name, []);
              for (const shee of dashboard.sheets) {
                this.databaseService
                  .getDocument("Sheets", shee)
                  .subscribe((sheet: SheetDB) => {
                    s = new Sheet(sheet.id, sheet.name, []);
                    for (const wid of sheet.widgets) {
                      this.databaseService
                        .getDocument("Widgets", wid)
                        .subscribe((widget: WidgetDB) => {
                          // TODO check widget type
                          s.widgets.push(
                            new Widget(
                              widget.id,
                              widget.name,
                              widget.position,
                              widget.isDeveloped,
                              widget.type,
                            ),
                          );
                          this.dataService.changeProjectData(this.project);
                        });
                    }
                  });
              }
              d.sheets.push(s);
              this.dataService.changeProjectData(this.project);
            });
          this.project.dashboards.push(d);
          this.dataService.changeProjectData(this.project);
        }
        console.log("Project", this.project);
        this.router.navigate(["dashboard"]);
      },
      err => {
        console.log("Error loading project data from database ", err);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The code iterates through each hierachie: Project -> Dashboards -> Sheets -> Widgetes. The idea is that when each lower hierarchical element is loaded it gets push to the upper mother element. But when executing the code all objects but the project are undefined. Does anybody know how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at subscriptions levels, the data that you want to push higher exist only in subscribe callback but you want to use it from the outside. And also take a look at some rxjs methods such as combinelatest switchmap and so on tosplit this code into something that will be comfortable for the other developers.